# Animating an Expander using a Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to animate an Expander with a Behavior during Expanded and Collapsed events, it does work when expanding but not when collapsing. After spending quite some time to try figure out the cause (Visibility == Collapsed) I couldn't make it animate when collapsing.

There's a sort of hack on grabbing initial content size, the animation would certainly be incorrect in case of content changing but there is no event of kind ContentChanged to hook onto and grab the new size in case the content is changed.

Behavior:

```cs
public class AnimatedExpanderBehavior : Behavior<Expander>
{
    public Duration Duration { get; set; }
    private Size ContentSize { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Collapsed += AssociatedObject_Collapsed;
        AssociatedObject.Expanded += AssociatedObject_Expanded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Collapsed -= AssociatedObject_Collapsed;
        AssociatedObject.Expanded -= AssociatedObject_Expanded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = sender as Expander;
        if (expander != null)
        {
            var name = expander.Content as FrameworkElement;
            if (name != null)
            {
                // Does not happen, collapses instantly instead
                var animation = new DoubleAnimation(name.ActualHeight, 0, Duration);
                name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, animation);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = sender as Expander;
        if (expander != null)
        {
            var name = expander.Content as UIElement;
            if (name != null)
            {
                // Grabbing initial content size
                if (ContentSize.Width <= 0 && ContentSize.Height <= 0)
                {
                    name.Measure(new Size(9999, 9999));
                    ContentSize = name.DesiredSize;
                }
                var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, ContentSize.Height, Duration);
                name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, animation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<Expander>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:AnimatedExpanderBehavior Duration="0:0:0.2" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Red" />
</Expander>
```

Interestingly I've been looking at how Windows UI does it, I was absolutely certain that it was doing it both ways while in fact it does it only during expansion.

Is there any sort of limitation that would prevent achieving such animation when collapsing ?

**Edit**

New code, however it does not adjust when content changes while the original expander does:

```cs
    private void AssociatedObject_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = sender as Expander;
        if (expander != null)
        {
            var name = expander.Content as FrameworkElement;
            if (name != null)
            {
                _expandSite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                double height;
                if (_firstExpansion)
                {
                    name.Measure(new Size(9999, 9999));
                    height = name.DesiredSize.Height;
                    _firstExpansion = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    height = name.RenderSize.Height;
                }
                var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, height, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d)));
                name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, animation);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is the `Expander.ControlTemplate` holds a `ContentPresenter` whose `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed` as soon as `IsExpanded` becomes `false`

Thus even if your animation actually runs you never get to see it since it's parent is invisible. This `ContentPresenter` is called `ExpandSite`(from default template) and we can get a hold of it in the behavior with something like

```cs
private UIElement _expandSite;

protected override void OnAttached() {
  base.OnAttached();
  AssociatedObject.Collapsed += AssociatedObject_Collapsed;
  AssociatedObject.Expanded += AssociatedObject_Expanded;
  AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, args) => {
    _expandSite = AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("ExpandSite", AssociatedObject) as UIElement;
    if (_expandSite == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
  };
}

...

private void AssociatedObject_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var expander = sender as Expander;
  if (expander == null)
    return;

  var name = expander.Content as FrameworkElement;
  if (name == null)
    return;

  _expandSite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  var animation = new DoubleAnimation(name.ActualHeight, 0, Duration);
  animation.Completed += (o, args) => {
    _expandSite.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, null);
  };
  name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, animation);
}

private void AssociatedObject_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var expander = sender as Expander;
  if (expander == null)
    return;

  var name = expander.Content as FrameworkElement;
  if (name == null)
    return;

  if (name.DesiredSize.Width <= 0 && name.DesiredSize.Height <= 0)
    name.Measure(new Size(9999, 9999));

  _expandSite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, name.DesiredSize.Height, Duration);
  animation.Completed += (o, args) => name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, null);
  name.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, animation);
}
```

The reason why we also set `_expandSite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` before the expanding animation is cos when we set the `Visibility` of `ExpandSite` from the Behavior, it takes precedence and the `Trigger.Setter` from the default `Style` is ignored. Thus we got to manage `Visibility` in both cases.

You do have an alternate to this entire process. Don't use a `Behavior<...>`, instead just provide a custom `Style` for the `Expander` and specify `Trigger.Enter/ExitActions` accordingly in the `ControlTemplate` to animate `Visibility` of `ExpandSite` and your `Content`.

**Update:**

Sample Download: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn2glmjioo19khg/WpfApplication17.rar)

The problem with re-sizing was there in your original code as well. It has nothing to do with the answer I posted as all we added was toggling `Visibility` of `ExpandSite`. That issue is due to the animation freezing the `Height` property of the `Content` thereby not allowing any future changes to appear unless via a following animation.

This ^^ sample should have the fix for that as well.

Comment: It works great except that on first expansion nothing happens, I managed that using a boolean that decides which height from RenderSize or DesiredSize to use but well, the expander does not adjust itself when its content changes unless it's expanded or collapsed while the original style does. I think I'll just forget about it for now as I can't get it working without having side-effects affecting the original behavior. But any ideas are welcome !

Comment: @Aybe this maybe because of the animation holding onto the height property when it's being animated and locking it due to animation precedence. On both the expanded/collapsed animations from the completed event set the height of the "name" element to its ActualHeight then start a new height animation on the same with the second argument null to effectively remove the animation precedence. This should then let the animation to not prevent future resizes.

Comment: @Aybe I've updated my answer with a download link to a sample that should have the fix for the re-sizing issue as well. I did not need any bool value like you mentioned for the animation on first expand. Try the download and see if it behaves differently for you. In the sample you got two buttons to modify the size of the `Expander.Content` you can use to test size changes.